Gitlab docker upgrade destroys my database
I planned to upgrade my GitLab server in a docker setup from 16.8-ee to 17.2-ee and I have found no relative upgrade paths for this, so I assume it is okay to upgrade to 17.2 directly. Using the gitlab's official documentation on upgrading GitLab via docker.
Upon starting the new container, I noticed that I cannot login anymore, it shows the invalid credentials error. Upon checking gitlab-rails console, I have found out that the users were erased and the record only shows 1 user.
User.all.each { |user| puts "#{user.username}: #{user.state}"}
root: active
=> [#<User id:1 @root>]
Any ideas how to fix it?
Here is my docker run command.
sudo docker run --detach --hostname gitlab.example.com --publish 443:443 --publish 8080:80 --publish 122:22 --name gitlab --restart always --volume $GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab --volume $GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab --volume $GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab --volume /srv/gitlab/config/ssl/gitlab.crt:/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.crt --volume /srv/gitlab/config/ssl/gitlab.key:/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.key:ro --shm-size 256m gitlab/gitlab-ee:15.11.13-ee.0sudo docker run --detach --hostname gitlab.tm.jfe-eng.co.jp --publish 443:443 --publish 8080:80 --publish 122:22 --name gitlab --restart always --volume $GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab --volume $GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab --volume $GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab --volume /srv/gitlab/config/ssl/gitlab.crt:/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.crt --volume /srv/gitlab/config/ssl/gitlab.key:/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.key:ro --shm-size 256m <gitlab image>

I only reattached previously used volumes and did not create a new volume for the new container. I am also suspecting that it is not really the upgrade that disrupts the database record, it might be due to a step in upgrading that requires to remove the container before proceeding.

Lots of questions coming to my mind. Did you initially started your container with the correct volumes mounted ? After that when you upgraded did you start with the correct volumes attached ?

We also need more information like how do you setup gitlab with docker and provide any scripts you have relevant

Yes, it was working with multiple project repositories and users and such before. Yes I only copied the previous docker command I ran to run the container.

What happens if you delete the current container , start it again but instead of image 17.2-ee you try image 16.8-ee . Check if that restores your previous repos or if  the databases are corrupted

Will have this lined up on my troubleshooting steps... So far, I was able to dig up an old snapshot of the server back when it was still 15.3-ee, I tried upgrading it (actually removing container) based on the upgrade path, but upon finishing first upgrade version path, it still produces a fresh-like installation, discarding previous data on the same volume.
